# C# ReportViewer 2010 - Series Color Differ from Legend Color

Tags: c#, winforms, report-viewer2010

I have a report with a column chart, on it i have made a simple "Iif" to make sure the colors always stay the same based on the grouped property,

The series color show just fine, but the legend color only picks the first item and the rest is black.
[image: Sample]

I really have no ideia whats going on, does anyone have any ideia what could i do?

Ah, if i set the color to automatic the legend works as it should.. not sure why its not respecting with custom values,
Thanks!

Comment: try this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/MSWinWebChart/thread/3506aba8-eb38-4513-a2cb-6da10dc1a720

Comment: Hm im using ReportViewer for the charts not the ms charts component directly..

Anyway, i did manage to "fix" it.. The DataPoint for this chart was "Count(Fields!ID.Value)".. if i changed it to "Sum(Fields!ID.Value)" it works. Did some workaround in the data label to show the count and im good to go..

Comment: Of course its a terrible solution/workaround.. If someone have any clue on how to properly solve this issue i would be very grateful! Thanks!

Comment: Last thing.. changing to Sum(Fields!ID.Value) wasnt a good ideia since it would make the bar chart not real (since summing the id isnt exatacly the same of the count lol).. so i changed again to Sum(1) lol